# Lenovo Yoga display flickering when using WiFi on Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, 21.04

Tags: wireless, multiple-monitors, display, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Yoga 530-14ikb. Installed all three versions of Ubuntu and had the same problem on all of them. I have tried to turn off the automatic brightness off, switching to Wayland, added kernel boot parameter i915.edp_vswing=2 but have not had any luck. Tried pretty much everything I was able to find online. When I add external display with HDMI then the external display works as it should but the laptop display is still flickering. This only happens when I turn the WiFi on. I tried connecting with Ethernet and then again it worked just fine. The issue is only on WiFi and only with the laptop display.

Comment: While this is not a *great* solution, one option is to not use the 2.4GHz band for WiFi. If you can use just the 5GHz bands, the flickering generally disappears.

Comment: @matigo Thanks! That's good to know. Also it's very interesting why that would fix the issue. Would getting an additional WiFi dongle help then? I move around a lot, hotels and airbnbs don't always give the option to choose.

Comment: I honestly don’t know if a dongle will resolve the issue, as I’ve never disassembled a Yoga 530. My guess is that the WiFi antenna is too tightly bound do the video signal cable, which is creating interference. Using a higher WiFi frequency puts the interference out of range of the video signal … but it’s just a guess. If you have a dongle to test with, please do. If you don’t, maybe it would be better to borrow one before investing in one 